# Should I remove an element when it is out of viewport?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, svg

Should I remove an element dynamically using jQuery (or pure JS if that's faster) when it is translated out of viewport and won't enter it again? Does that improve memory usage or performance? Or should I ignore it to be removed by the garbage collecter because it does it best (if it does it in essence)?

EDIT: To make it clearer, here is a practical explanation:

Let's say I have 100 circles having their translateX animated:

```
$("circle").each(function(i, el){
    $(el).animate({translateX: -100});
});
```

Now all the circles are out of viewport (since SVG's coordinate system starts at the top left 0,0). Should my code have removing in it, as in the following:

```
$("circle").each(function(i, el){
    $(el).animate({translateX: -100}, {complete: function()
    $(el).remove();
});
});
```

??

Comment: Are you animating on a canvas or similar view space?

Comment: Wont it be easier to add a `.remove()` at end of animation coding?

Comment: The answer will depend on whether you are trying to improve animation frame rate (removal probably not necessary because the browser will exclude them anyway) or memory usage (yes, if it is a long running animation or there are a lot of circles).  The most reliable answer is to try it yourself and see.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes!

The garbage collector works behind the scenes to handle releasing the memory of objects you are no longer using. But unless you somehow let it go (that is, tell the runtime system that you don't want it anymore), the garbage collector will only handle it at the end of execution!

Here is a really great guide to memory management for a high-level language (e.g., javascript) developer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management